# Text - on mouse over an word - change the color, on click over the word - play audio, on mouse out - change text color

Tags: javascript, html, colors, onclick, html5-audio

I found difficult to make it work because im not familiar with js.

I want to write an  an line using many words, but every word have own functionality.
Example: On mouse over word-1 change the text color to red, on click play audio-1, on mouse out change the text color to black again. This way for every word on the line, using different audio files for different words.

Right now i used ty this, but i cant manage it to work. Any help?

```
      <script>
function playAudio(url) {
  new Audio(url).play();
}
    </script>

<br><font onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio1.mp3')">Word1</br>
   
<br><font onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio2.mp3')">word2</br>
   
<br><font onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio3.mp3')">word3<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the  tag is outdated. It does not function in HTML5.

You can use `<p>` to make your functions work:

```
    <script>
  function playAudio(url) {
    new Audio(url).play();
  }
      </script>
  
  <br><p onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio1.mp3')">Word1</p</br>
     
  <br><p onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio2.mp3')">word2</p></br>
     
  <br><p onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio3.mp3')">word3</p><br>
```

The `<p>` paragraphs have a 100% width (the whole page) so their with has to be set to something smaller or `fit-content`. Otherwise you will be able to hover or click on the elements at positions where there is no text.